# Which Java matrix libraries allow the valuation of the matrix logarithm

Tags: java, matrix, numerical-methods

Which Java matrix libraries allow the valuation of the matrix logarithm? Is matrix exponential included?

Comment: Note: I found this "duplicate" which was asking this question related to Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821767/how-to-calculate-matrix-logarithm - however, the original question is not longer available and while there are questions about matrix logarithm there are non about Java implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The jeigen library - a wrapper for eigen has implementations of logm and expm.
https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen

Comment: I have just edited my answer to my own question, because the jeigen lib has added support for logm and expm